# JSON object error in login and register form

Tags: android, json, eclipse

I am new to programming android apps, i have created a app which requires user authentication from sql server.

when i login from emulator with initialized user on server i get error from log cat as. below

```
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.ideals.ideal.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:131)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.ideals.ideal.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-19 13:06:07.806: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  ... 4 more
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427): Activity com.ideals.ideal.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40565160 that was originally added here
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.ideals.ideal.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40565160 that was originally added here
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at com.ideals.ideal.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:123)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at com.ideals.ideal.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:97)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-19 13:06:09.556: E/WindowManager(427):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can anyone help me with error

code posting

JSON

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Login activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // php login script location:

    // localhost :
    // testing on your device
    // put your local ip instead, on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    // or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL =
    // "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

    // testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.google.com/login.php";

// above url has been changed

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_user);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_reg:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Myidealmain.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: which class i should post?? vinay

Comment: post LoginActivity.java

Comment: post LoginActivity class

Comment: The problem is in file LoginActivity.java line 131

Comment: henry your observation is correct i have misplaced user and password variables

Comment: I will appriciate if you can tell me how to read through logcat

Comment: @Shweta you already used Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE)); go to DDMS and click on device, select the device then come back to java mode click on logcat!

Comment: @Shweta android Protip: "Always use this AccountManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html " for any login which gives provides access to a centralized registry of the user's on-line accounts, for further enhancing say good bye to buggy Async task and use volley with GSON, Jackson parsers!

Comment: Hi Shweta please check my answer i updated loginactivity java file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the below codes inside the `onPostExecute`

`doInBackground` runs in a worker thread which cannot do any **UI** work

```
if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Myidealmain.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
```

**EDIT:**

Remove below lines

```
String username = user.getText().toString();
String password = pass.getText().toString();
```

and modified

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_login:   
            new AttemptLogin(user.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString()).execute();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_reg:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

and inside your `AsyncTask`

```
                String username;
                String password;
                public AttemptLogin(String username, String password) {
                    this.username = username;
                    this.password = password;
                }
```

**EDIT:**

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

                String username;
                String password;
                int success;
                public AttemptLogin(String username, String password) {
                    this.username = username;
                    this.password = password;
                }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (file_url != null) {
               Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Myidealmain.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: shall i replace existing if statement??

Comment: it give error for variable success?? and json on eclipse error checking

Comment: @Shweta from this `json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);` what will return.

Comment: thanks tamilan for your time but i have tried after correcting code line 131, Now i am getting toast message of -- Database Error 1: please try again.

Comment: i am able to register user using same database but not login

Comment: @Shweta you have not initilized **user**,**pass** edit text.  same like that You can not get the edittext value in doInBackground.

Comment: Many thanks for your time Tamilan can you update entire class and post it so that i wont miss anything

Comment: username    --    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_user);
password  ---- inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw);

Comment: Tamilian are you online please reply

Comment: @Shweta Sorry for the late response. check my second edit i posted your `AttemptLogin` `AsyncTask` try out that.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is likely here :

```
 String username = user.getText().toString();
```

If you read your LogCat error, the important part is here :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ideals.ideal.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground
```

You have a NullPointerException inside the doInBackground method of your AsyncTask.
You are trying to read the value of the `EditText user` but that field has not been initialized in your code, you need to use findViewById inside LoginActivity.onCreate (like you did for EditText inputEmail), for the moment `user` is probably null.

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground` runs in a worker thread which cannot do any UI work

Please update LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
   // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // JSONObject output
    JSONObject json=null;


    // php login script location:

    // localhost :
    // testing on your device
    // put your local ip instead, on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    // or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL =
    // "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

    // testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.google.com/login.php";

// above url has been changed

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_user);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_reg:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {

                    return "success";
                } 

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();



            if (file_url != null && file_url.equals("success")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Myidealmain.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you sir, are trying to dismiss a `Dialog` after you finish the Activity.

notice that in `doInBackground` you call `finish` and then in the `onPostExecute`, you call      `pDialog.dismiss();`

if you try and touch the UI by adding or removing Views you'll experience `WindowLeaked` exceptions as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2850573/1056359)